# Jquery Sortable function aligment is not working very well with css

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi i use a jquery sortable codes for my notes dashboard. But some note windows are small and some note windows are big. So there is a empty areas between windows. So my note dashboard dont look well. Anybody have any solution for this problem ?

I am sending css and php code below

```
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 1120px; }
#sortable li { margin: 0px; float: left; width: 349px; padding:0px; padding-bottom:10px; background-position: top; }
</style>`



<ul id="sortable">
<?php while ($outputline = mysql_fetch_array($getcategory)) { ?>
    <li id="<?php echo $outputline["note_id"]; ?>">
        <?php echo $outputline["note_head"]; ?><br>
        <?php echo $outputline["detail"]; ?>
    </li>
 <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This is my note dashboard